# pass variable into where mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-variables

Cannot get the query to run, throwing error on the `@searchin` variable. 
Probably very simple but cannot see it.

```
set @search = "chip";
set @searchin = "CompanyName";

select * from con_search where @searchin like concat ('%',@search,'%')
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: How does PHP fit into all this?

Comment: Is `@Searchin` supposed to be a column name? This needs to be dynamic sql, if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, however you should sanatize the data going into it

```
set @search = 'chip';
set @searchin = 'CompanyName';
set @SQL = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM con_search WHERE `", @searchin, "` LIKE CONCAT('%'", @search, "'%');";
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```